# Leading term of $\det (A + \lambda B)$

Tags: matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices. If $B$ is nonsingular, then the polynomial $p(\lambda) = \det (A - \lambda B)$ is clearly the characteristic polynomial of $B^{-1}A$ times $\det B$.

What is known about the degree and the leading order coefficient of this polynomial if $B$ is singular? I am especially interested in the case when $B$ is skew-symmetric and $n$ is odd.

Comment: Interesting. One approach might be to consider the case when $A$ is nonsingular and write it as $\det(1 - \lambda A^{-1} B)$. The "leading order" then becomes "multiplicity of the root $0$".

Comment: Have you tried to unitarily diagonalise $B$ and then use the matrix determinant lemma?